# SharePoint 2010 Solutions using .NET 4.5

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, .net

I am creating a solution (wsp file) that will be installed on a SharePoint 2010 Server.  The solution uses a third party DLL which was built on `.NET 4.5`.  I have created my solution using the target framework of `.NET 4.5` to accommodate this third party DLL, but I am not able to add the solution as SP 2010 is based on `.NET 3.5.`  Is there an update to SP2010 that will allow for .NET 4.5 based solutions?

Saul

Answer (score 2):

Well kind of, that upgrade is SharePoint 2013.

In your case you're probably best off splitting you solution into two:

- a seperate web service or windows service using 4.5 which hosts the dll
- the wsp part in 3.5 calling this service

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 does not support access from .NET Framework 4 or being run in a .NET Framework 4 app domain. If you must support the .NET Framework 4, we recommend that you develop a web service that uses the .NET Framework 4 and then connect to it from SharePoint. All server-side customizations directly for SharePoint 2010 still need to be either the .NET Framework 3.5 or the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

For more information, see the following MSDN Library topics.

- [Requirements for Developing SharePoint Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231582.aspx)
- [How to: Set the Correct Target Framework and CPU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407621.aspx)

Source: [NET Framework support in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/07/14/net-framework-support-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)